# datahub 505 HTTP Version Not Supported

Tags: nginx, hybris-data-hub, http-status-code-505

I have started datahub with steps from
https://datahubproject.io/docs/quickstart

and then add nginx with conf

```
upstream datahub-front {
    server localhost:9002;
}

server {
    server_name  datahub.myhost.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://datahub-front;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    listen 80; 
}
```

all works fine at
http://datahub.myhost.com:9002

but at
http://datahub.myhost.com

i got

```
Request URL: https://datahub.myhost.com/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 505 HTTP Version Not Supported
```

I thing some cfg set up in nginx can fix the problem. pls help

Comment: Hi ! Please, would you try with `proxy_pass http://localhost:9002` to route to port 9002 ?

Comment: Glad to see my answer has been relevant :) Would you say us which fix has actually solve your issue ? `proxy_pass` or `http` related lines ?

Comment: I  have add all )

Comment: Ok ^^ Thx for the feeback :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the config I use for a specific location which targets a specific port on my public server :

```
location /somelocation/ {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
```

In your case, I think that the proxy_path must indicate the real port (9002 in your case), but the `$http_upgrade` sounds fine for a `505` error too ;)

Comment: for me the critical line was the `proxy_http_version 1.1;` directive